# Zend_Cache usage howtos

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache

are there any good tutorials on zend cache except their official documentation ?

Comment: Do you ask for Zend Framework 1 or 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a hard time following the Zend manual as well. This article looks pretty good: http://webhole.net/2009/11/27/how-to-cache-pages-with-zend/

Comment: Well considering I wrote my answer in 2010 and the post was from 2009, that makes sense.